How to display a modal drawer from NavigationRail in Flutter
I'm learning Flutter and was trying to create something similar to the NavigationRail in the Material3 website that when hovering over the "develop" icon for example, it seems to display a Drawer as a sub menu.
   -> [
I tried a couple ways:

adding the Drawer to the Row children. This method works closer than any other, however, when the drawer is displayed it pushes the rest of the items in the row (it does not behave as a Modal that is on top of the rest)

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
      children: [
        NavigationRail(
          leading: FloatingActionButton(
            elevation: 0,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          ),
          labelType: labelType,
          groupAlignment: groupAlignment,
          onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
              if (_selectedIndex == 1) {
                print("triggered");
                _drawerKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
              } else {
                _drawerKey.currentState?.closeDrawer();
              }
            });
          },
          destinations: [
            NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/logo/logo.png'),
                selectedIcon: Image.asset('assets/logo/logo.png'),
                label: const Text('Home')),
            const NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.precision_manufacturing_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.precision_manufacturing),
                label: Text('Lab Orders')),
            const NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.domain_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.domain),
                label: Text('Customers')),
          ],
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        ),
        const VerticalDivider(
          thickness: 1,
          width: 1,
        ),
        const NavigationDrawer(
          selectedIndex: -1,
          children: [
            NavigationDrawerDestination(
                icon: Icon(null), label: Text('Create Order')),
            NavigationDrawerDestination(
                icon: Icon(null), label: Text('Order Status')),
            NavigationDrawerDestination(
                icon: Icon(null), label: Text('Report Breakage')),
            NavigationDrawerDestination(
                icon: Icon(null), label: Text('Update Order'))
          ],
        ),
        const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/logo/logo.png'))
      ],
    ));
  }



Adding the drawer to the scaffold and using ScaffoldState.openDrawer(). This does displays the drawer as modal but the drawer shows from the edge of the screen and covers the navigation rail.

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: const NavigationDrawer(
        selectedIndex: -1,
        children: [
          NavigationDrawerDestination(
              icon: Icon(null), label: Text('Create Order')),
          NavigationDrawerDestination(
              icon: Icon(null), label: Text('Order Status')),
          NavigationDrawerDestination(
              icon: Icon(null), label: Text('Report Breakage')),
          NavigationDrawerDestination(
              icon: Icon(null), label: Text('Update Order'))
        ],
      ),,
        body: Row(
      children: [
        NavigationRail(
          leading: FloatingActionButton(
            elevation: 0,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          ),
          labelType: labelType,
          groupAlignment: groupAlignment,
          onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
              if (_selectedIndex == 1) {
                print("triggered");
                _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
              } else {
                _scaffoldKey.currentState?.closeDrawer();
              }
            });
          },
          destinations: [
            NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/logo/Optilab-logo.png'),
                selectedIcon: Image.asset('assets/logo/Optilab-logo.png'),
                label: const Text('Home')),
            const NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.precision_manufacturing_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.precision_manufacturing),
                label: Text('Lab Orders')),
            const NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.domain_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.domain),
                label: Text('Customers')),
            const NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.inventory_2_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.inventory_2),
                label: Text('Inventory')),
            const NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.receipt_long_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.receipt_long),
                label: Text('Billing'))
          ],
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        ),
        const VerticalDivider(
          thickness: 1,
          width: 1,
        ),
        const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/logo/Optilab-logo.png'))
      ],
    ));
  }


Any ideas or pointers on to how can i accomplish the same behavior as in the material site?
